# Printing scrapy data to csv

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

Hi I started scrapy recently,and wrote a crawler. But when outputting the data to csv,they are all printed in a single row. How can print each data to its own row?

I my case am printing links from a website. It works well when printed in json format.

Here's the code.

The items.py file.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Item ,Field
class ErcessassignmentItem(scrapy.Item):
# define the fields for your item here like:
# name = scrapy.Field()
link = Field()
#pass
```

The mycrawler.py

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector # deprecated
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from ercessAssignment.items import ErcessassignmentItem

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
name ="ercessSpider"
allowed_domains =["site_url"]
start_urls = ["site_url"]

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = Selector(response)
    links = hxs.xpath("//p")
    items = []
    for linkk in links:
        item = ErcessassignmentItem()
        item["link"] = linkk.xpath("//a/@href").extract()
        items.append(item)
        return items`
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have proper indentation in code

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Item ,Field
class ErcessassignmentItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    link = Field()
```

Then in your spider, do not use `return`, your for loop will run only once and you will only have 1 row printed in CSV, instead use `yield`
Second, where is your code to put items into CSV? I guess you are using scrapy's default way of storing items,
in case you already do not know, please run your scraper like

```
scrapy crawl ercessSpider -o my_output.csv
```

Your spider code should be like this, notice changes I made

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector # deprecated
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from ercessAssignment.items import ErcessassignmentItem

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
name ="ercessSpider"
allowed_domains =["site_url"]
start_urls = ["site_url"]

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = Selector(response)
    links = hxs.xpath("//p")
    for linkk in links:
        item = ErcessassignmentItem()
        item["link"] = linkk.xpath("//a/@href").extract()
        yield item
```

Comment: Its not yet working as I expected. I guess am missing something I can't understand. the crawler stills output many data(links) into one row in the csv file. What am looking for is the crawler should print every link in its own row in the csv file. ie if there are 10 links from the website, then the 10 links should all be in their own rows in the csv file.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
for linkk in links:
    item = ErcessassignmentItem()
    item["link"] = xpath("//a/@href").extract()[linkk]
    yield item
```

this works good in css selector but if above two solutions are not working then you can try this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code above does not `print` anything. Moreover, I don't see any `.csv` part. Also, your `items` list created in `parse()` will never be longer than 1 due to something that looks like an indentation error to me (i.e. you `return` after the first iteration of the `for-loop`. For better readability, you could use the [for/else](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html) construct here:

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = Selector(response)
    links = hxs.xpath("//p")
    items = []
    for linkk in links:
        item = ErcessassignmentItem()
        item["link"] = linkk.xpath("//a/@href").extract()
        items.append(item)
    else:                               # after for loop is finished
        # either return items
        # or print link in items here without returning
        for link in items:              # take one link after another
            print link                  # and print it in one line each
```

Comment: Hi! there was no indention error! it was a coping mistake. 
am using the scrapy default of printing to csv something like this.
 `scrapy crawl crawlername -o csvfile.csv`
Still the problem isn't getting solved as I expected. for instance the many links are printed on the same row. I wanted the every link to be on its own row.